# Convert POST Request in C# to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, .net-core

I need to convert this C# code to JavaScript:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string SECRET_KEY = "my_secret_key";

Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\1.jpg");
string imagebase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

var content = new StringContent(imagebase64);

var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.openalpr.com/v2/recognize_bytes?recognize_vehicle=1&country=us&secret_key=" + SECRET_KEY, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var byteArray = buffer.ToArray();
var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

I tried do this in JavaScript:

```js
var file = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0];
getBase64(file).then(
    data => $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.openalpr.com/v2/recognize_bytes?recognize_vehicle=1&country=br&secret_key=' + secret_key,
        contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
        data: data,
        success: function (ret) {
            console.log(ret);
        },
        error: function (ret) {
            console.log(ret);
        }
    }
```

Basically, both are intended converting an image to Base64 and send via POST to an API endpoint.

The conversion works as expected in both cases, however I get an error in JS.

Error 400: Error loading image

I don't have access to back end of this API and I don't have support.
I think some requirements are different, maybe the format of the type or something...

Comment: Based on the [OpenALPR JS client](https://github.com/openalpr/cloudapi/blob/master/javascript/src/api/DefaultApi.js#L81), it looks like the `recognize_bytes` endpoint expects JSON in the request body, so it's possible that that's an issue.

Comment: Separately, are you planning on having this JS code run client-side or in Node.js? If client-side, note that it's generally a BAD IDEA to expose your API secrets to clients. Then anyone can look at the requests leaving their machine and steal your secrets. Instead, pass the API call through your own server.

Comment: I was planing use in a mobile app with WebView. The page was not exposed to be access out of webview. But i dont know if this have more risks

Comment: Even in that case, the user could still inspect all web requests leaving the device (for example, by connecting via USB and using the Chrome debugger or by using [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor&hl=en_US)) and parse out your secret.

Answer (score 0):

did you debugged the file variable where you are getting the base64 format . first try that and if this is not working try the below one to convert file to base64:

```
const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});
```

to call above method use : `toBase64(file)`

once the post request is formed check in the postman tool . I hope it will resolve your query .